# iPhone 6 with iOS 8.4 and the iOS sdk 9.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm developing and app using Xcode 7.1, when running the application on an iPhone 6 device with iOS 8.4 i'm encountering some layout problems.
But when i run the same project on and iPhone 5s with the iOS 8.4 system or and iPhone 6 Plus with iOS 9.1 the issue doesn't seem to be happening.

A nice example is that I'm loading a static html page from the device bundle and its scaling the web view content so that it allows horizontal scrolling (iPhone 6 with 8.4) and when running on a iPhone 6 Plus with 9.1 this issue doesn't occur (it also works fine on iPhone 5s with iOS 8.4). It seems like only the iPhone 6 with the iOS 8.4 is having this problem. Has anyone else had this problem ?

Comment: Sounds like an autolayout issue. Did you try running that code in iPhone 6 simulator with iOS 9?

Comment: Yes i have also tried that and on the iPhone 6 simulator with iOS 9 and i works fine but with iOS 8.4 it bugs the webview